# Android for dummies example error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am new to the android programming and I am studying it through "Android Application Development for dummies ". In the book there is an example of Task Reminder app. The problem I am facing is that it is not showing the built in image ic_menu
_add when run on the emulator. I am using Android 4.1. following are the codes of xml file and main activity file.

(list_menu.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 

<item android:id="@+id/menu_insert"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
android:title="@string/menu_insert" />


</menu>
```

(ReminderListActivity.java)

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_reminder_list, menu);
    MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
    mi.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I have tried everything that I could possibly do. I have run this code with Android 2.2, 2.1 as well but found same problem.

many thanks in advance

Comment: The code is available at the link below. Is it the same as you have? Perhaps the author has updated it. http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/8X/04707701/DOWNLOAD/770184TaskReminder.zip

Answer (score 0):

change your project target to android 8 (or less than 14) and it will work.Android 4.1 don't have a menu button

Comment: I think his menu is showing on 4.1 but he cant see the icon. Its strange as i agree that 4.1 doesn't have a menu button

Comment: did you see a menu button in your app(the three dots)?

Comment: Hi, I did try this with project target set to 7 and 8 but this won't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you inflate two xml menus in the same method ? check your onCreateOptionsMenu method

Answer (score 0):

use this in API level 8 working not sure in 4.1

```
 public static final int ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX = Menu.FIRST;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0, ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX, 0, "Add").setIcon( android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code but unfortunately this code you provided did not work. The result was same as previously described.